# Journey away and back at close to the speed of light $c$

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, speed-of-light, coordinate-systems, time-dilation

If a person drives away from a clock tower at a speed close to 
$c$ for one whole day, and then drives back to it at the same speed (for another day), what would he see during each of the journeys?

I suppose that while driving away from the clock, it would appear to be "frozen", but what would the person see on the clock while driving back to it?

How many days have passed for someone who stood near that clock until our traveler got back from his 2 days road trip? (more than 2 days or exactly 2 days)?

Comment: Could you be more specific with your question? What speed is the driver moving at relative to c? You should note two things: if the driver is moving at the speed c then they experience no physical time, so the idea of them travelling for two days is meaningless until you tell us what speed they are travelling at. Also it's important to note that you're essentially describing the twin paradox, research the twin paradox and you may be able to answer your own question.

Comment: @Ollie113 As I stated in the original question, the speed is close to C. Meaning 0.999999% of speed of light or however you want to formalize it. To my superficial understing, the question here is not the same as the twin paradox since I am referring to what is actually seen on the clock during the travel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have produced [some videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLvGnzGhIWTGR-O332xj0sToA0Yk1X7IuI) of a there and back trip with clocks at the near end, far end, and in the car(!), as well as distributed through the scene.  It is not a constant speed scenario; it uses constant acceleration.  The (terse) explanatory text is reproduced below:

> The twin "paradox" (in quotes because it is NOT a real paradox!) is a basic teaching scenario for Special Relativity: http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics... This is a series of visualizations of the journey from the point of view of the traveling twin, who flies 20 light years away from his home station then returns. The journey consists of four parts, joined together. The first quarter is an acceleration away from the station. During the second and third quarters the ship accelerates towards the station (so that at the half way point the ship is stationary 20 light years away). In the fourth quarter the ship accelerates away from the station in order to come to rest there. The total coordinate travel time (shown as a red dot in the top left HUD clock) is 43.711/58.918 years for acceleration at earth/moon gravity levels, whilst proper time (green dot) is 12.101/38.694 years. The yellow dot represents the time the traveler would see on the station clock face through a very powerful telescope! The octahedral stations (spaced one light year apart and one light year to the left of the flight path) are all synchronized to coordinate time and rotate once over the course of the whole journey. There is a 2x2 light year wall one light year beyond the far end of the journey, and large rectangular frames every 5 light years. Where a floor is shown it is 1 light year per stripe, and there are small 1 ly milestone spheres along the way, with a larger one every five light years. The flights are rendered without relativistic effects and then for two values of acceleration (currently earth gravity and moon gravity). The distortion artifacts are due to aberration of light, the Doppler effect and the headlight effect. The earth gravity videos exhibit some nice penrose-terrel "rotation" effects. Magenta markers in a circle show where you really are in the scene (in the sense that things outside the circle are behind you, whilst those inside the circle are in front of you. Doppler shift = gamma for this circle), and grey markers show the circle where the doppler shift is 1 (gamma is in theory directly observable on this circle). These videos were made with POV-Ray (http://www.povray.org/) and avconv/ffmpeg (https://www.ffmpeg.org/) video encoding software. POV and support files are available from https://github.com/m4r35n357/FirstPer...